# AO Denoise Filter

Tags: opengl, image-processing, direct3d, ambient-occlusion, denoise

I'm trying to implement a filter to denoise ambient occlusion data.

What kind of filter do you suggest for the purpose?

The techniques I've come across are the following:

- Gaussian filter (doesn't preserve edges)
- Bilateral/Joint Bilateral filter (the one I've tried)
- Guided filter (never tried, looks intrinsically blurrier than bilateral)
- Gaussian + Edge detection (did't find good resources about the edge detection part, do you know any?)

I choose to implement a joint bilateral filter using view-space z values as input.

However, I'm having some trouble with that, in particular, I don't know if there's a way to fix the following issues:

**1. Artifacts at grazing angles:**

When looking at a surface almost edge-on, Z values changes rapidly in one dimensions (image space) while remain almost constant in the other. This causes the filter to smooth the image only in one dimension.
[image]

**2. "Jumps" across edges:**

Samples separated by (what I'd like the filter to consider) an edge are considered similar and influence each other's final value greatly. (They have the same Z).

[image]

**3. How to choose the correct parameters for the filter so that it consistently detects edges in the most scene-independent way possible?**

Do you have any suggestions? Are there other techniques out there that could help me?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?